# Некорректно работает ЧПУ

Tags: php, .htaccess

В .htaccess прописано следующее:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^www\.].*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9\-/]+)/$ /index.php?section=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9\-/]+)/([a-z0-9\-/]+)/$ /index.php?section=$1&act=$2 [L]
```

Проблема в том, что второй RewriteRule работает (например: `site.ru/catalog/`), а третий (например: `site.ru/page/contacts/`) нет, причем, если удалить второй, то третий заработает, в чем проблема?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^www\.].*$ [NC]` эта строка только мне кажется лишней?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у вас строка `site.ru/page/contacts/` подходит и под первое регулярное выражение.

Вам нужно убрать `/` из перечисления символов в квадратных скобках.

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9\-]+)/$ /index.php?section=$1 [L]
```

### Дополнение

И насколько я помню в URI не обязателен закрывающий слеш, так что ваш `.htaccess` должен выглядеть так

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^www\.].*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ /index.php?section=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-/]+)/?$ /index.php?section=$1&act=$2 [L]
```

Comment: теперь почему-то при переходе на `site.ru/page/contacts` перенаправляет на `http://page/contacts/`

Comment: @dikardRus кто перенаправляет? Вот тест – http://joxi.ru/vAWYJ7YiRRDKmW

Comment: обновил ответ, там опечатка закралась в последнем правиле

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает, только непонятно, почему когда заходишь на `site.ru/page/contacts/` открывается страница с url  `page/contacts//`. Переименовал страницу в contact и зашел на `site.ru/page/contact/` всё отработало хорошо.

Comment: @dikardRus это может ваш код редиректит, смотрите какие заголовки в ответе на запрос приходят